What do the offices of very junior faculty at Yale look like?
I am writing a novel and one of the characters is a brand new member of the faculty in the psychology department at Yale. She works there part time, and has a therapy practice in another location.
I want to describe her office, but I don't know how it would look. How big? Any windows? Would it be just hers or would she share?
EDI: Sorry for the off topic question, but thanks for the helpful comments and answers!

Go visit Yale and ask for a tour.

This question seems out of scope. It is also poorly tagged.

"Any windows?" Is this meant seriously? I.e., are there indeed some offices at some US universities that don't have windows?

@JochenGlueck Yes. My office in grad school did not have any windows. A few years later I had a 1 year position at a school where I had a window but it was so obscured by outside machinery (If I recall correctly air conditioning units) that there was almost no natural light let in.

"are there indeed some offices at some US universities that don't have windows" yes, this is quite common.

are there indeed some offices at some US universities that don't have windows? --- Of the 4 colleges/universities I've taught full-time at, I had a window at 2 of them and no window at 2 of them. One of the former I had two offices -- 2 years with a window and a 3rd year without a window, and one of the latter I had three offices -- 1 year without a window, different office for 2 years without a window, 1 year at still another office without a window.

@JochenGlueck Sometimes, people's offices are in the basement.

There might be photos at https://communications.yale.edu/yale-photos

Also, I did my undergrad at Yale, and the quality of offices was highly variable from department to department. English for example had very nice spaces, and math was in an old, almost falling apart pair of buildings. Also, from a writing standpoint, readers aren't going to care if your office description is not perfectly aligned with reality. (I did write a short story a while ago where I had to get the geography of Brandeis correct, but that was mainly because my spouse went there and she gets to look at all drafts so she insisted on changing things..)

Thanks for all the replies to my comment! I'm genuinely surprised. (I guess I always took it for granted that almost every office has a window. Turns out that I was quite wrong.)

From a brief look at the Yale Psychology department website, the Yale department does NOT train students to practice at psychologists or therapists, and is unlikely to hire a professor who practices rather than doing research into psychology (including research into what practices are effective for therapists).  Having a therapist teaching in the Yale psychology department is about as realistic as having a physician teaching in the Yale biology department (rather than in the medical school)

@AlexanderWoo I don't have a bunch of time to snoop the webpages further, but if there's some confirmatory evidence, I'd be happy to integrate it into my answer. I suspected the same as what you're saying, but I'm in math like you so am slightly shaky on what an academic route looks like for therapists.

@AlexanderWoo: I do not know about the Yale faculty specifically, but they do have Clinical Psychology. It is absolutely not far-fetched for clinical psychologists to be licensed and possibly practicing therapists or psychiatrists. Professorships in Clinical Psychology frequently require being a licensed therapist. Source: my wife is a professor of Clinical Psychology and a licensed therapist (though in Germany, not at Yale).

@StephanKolassa: And on that web page it says: "The Clinical Psychology area is dedicated to research and training in clinical science. The graduate program aspires to educate the next generation of leading academic and research psychologists and to create an environment for advancing research related to psychopathology and its treatment." - no mention of training future practicing clinical psychologists.

@AlexanderWoo: yes, and I wrote that I do not know about the situation at Yale specifically, but that this setup is not unheard of, at least on other parts of the Western world. I do wonder how many graduates of this program do become research scientists, and how many go on to be licensed as therapists. In Germany, the vast majority take the second route. Which is why I believe that requiring clinical psychologists to have at least a rudimentary understanding of therapy is a Good Thing. YMMV.

Your best bet to answer this question is to visit the psychology department at Yale in person.
That being said, if you're trying to be pedantically accurate, it sounds to me like you may need to do a little more research. Or perhaps not, but I think the following is useful advice for anybody in a similar situation in the future as well. As a commenter points out: pedantic accuracy may not be what you're going for.
I do appreciate, however, authors that don't over-embellish work conditions for academics. Our offices are often smaller and less attractive than they're portrayed in external media, even at wealthy places like Yale and especially for junior faculty.

[...] [She] is a brand new member of the faculty in the psychology department at Yale. She works there part time, and has a therapy practice in another location.

To figure out what offices you're trying to locate, you likely need to know what this character's job title is. Once you know a job title, you can visit Yale in person or call their psychology department's public number. A secretary will probably happily answer some short series of questions about what their offices look like.
If you want to be extremely accurate, you need to do research on what a typical career path looks like for a psychology professor and determine where in that path your character falls. Ultimately, you must decide whether your character is on an academic career path, or if they are an adjunct professor whose main job is their practice and perhaps teaches one class part-time. You can then ask about the job title you're interested in for the offices. You will already be slightly wrong to the reality in this latter case, as Yale's psychology department doesn't list themselves as hiring any adjuncts. In many places, adjuncts have no office, or a shared office, frequently without windows. Assistant professors likely have their own, I suspect with a window at Yale.

She works there part time, and has a therapy practice in another location.

As an aside, you may be taking some significant authorial license with this if you want your character to be going down the academic route and not just teaching a class once in awhile as an adjunct. I'm less experienced with how assistant professorships go in medicine, but in most disciplines being on the tenure-track at a place like Yale does not leave time in the day for a person to maintain a whole independent second job. I've heard of physicians and psychologists practicing as part of their tenure-track assignment, sometimes in a faculty practice that the university administers, but I don't think I've often heard of people maintaining an independent practice.

Thanks. I do know that quite a few psychologists do research and do clinical work (this is one of the differences between a PsyD and a PhD). I don't know the specific situation at Yale.
